# .net core 2 rejects request with 415 when I set Accept to text/csv

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

When i POST a request to my .net core 2 mvc backend it returns json data.

I want to optionally change the headers as so , which i will then return a csv file of the data for download

```
'Accept': 'text/csv',
'Content-Type': `text/csv; charset=utf-8`
```

I set the controller base class with this Produces filter

```
[Produces("application/json", "text/csv")]
```

But those headers always cause .net to return 415 Unsupported Media Type

The controller action looks like this

```
[HttpPost] 
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] PostArgs args)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You source of problem is `Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8` header.

`[FromBody]` forces MVC middleware to use the input formatter for model binding (I am talking about `PostArgs` model). And by default, ASP.NET Core registers only one, JSON input formatter. Cause you set `Content-Type`, middleware cannot use that default formatter (as `Content-Type` header says that data **in request body** should be processed as CSV, not JSON) and so it throws `415 Unsupported Media Type` error.

---

... *I want to optionally change the headers as so , which i will then return a csv file of the data for download*

Actually, it looks like you understand in wrong way what `Content-Type` header [does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type):

> **In requests**, (such as POST or PUT), the client tells the server what type of data is actually sent.

In other words, you only need to specify the [`Accept` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept), cause

> The `Accept` request HTTP header advertises which content types, expressed as MIME types, the client is able to understand. Using content negotiation, the server then selects one of the proposals.

And it is the server then, who uses a `Content-Type` header in responses to tell the client what the content type of the returned content **(in response)** actually is.

Answer (score 2):

To return `csv` data, you return a [`ContentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.contentresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0) rather than a `JsonResult` object. This allows you to define the `Content-Type`:

```
return new ContentResult("csv-data", "text/csv", 200);
```

If you want to return a physical file you could return a [FileResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fileresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0) object.

---

By default, the `Accepts` header isn't enforced. You can enforce it via configuration:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
});
```

In order to accept additional formats, you'll also need to add `InputFormatters`:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
    config.InputFormatters.Add(new TextInputFormatter())
    config.OutputFormatters.Add(new StringOutputFormatter());
});
```

Comment: I am not sure that is my issue. I am successfully returning a csv file when accept is application/json. The csv file generation and response headers are fine. My problem is that the request is being rejected with a 415 error before the action can execute when i set the accept header of the request to text/csv.

Comment: Are you returning `csv` data or POSTing `csv` data?